# Могу ли я использовать xkb везде, где могу использовать xlib?

Tags: linux, xorg

Могу ли я использовать функции из `xkb`, на любой системе, на которой установлен XServer и соотв. `xlib`?

Comment: Строго говоря, наверное, нет -). Хотя бы потому, что в зависимостях `xkb` утилит присутствует `libX11` (см. `ldd`), а у X-server-а (`/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg`) ее нет. Но, думаю, на практике всюду вместе с XServer установлены и нужные xkb библиотеки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[x window system](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) ­— это клиент и сервер.

и если с [сервером](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver) (в отношении [расширения xkb](https://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/)) вопросов фактически нет: собрать актуальную версию **без** *xkb* — дело нетривиальное (судя по наличию каталога xkb и вообще содержимому configure.ac),

то с [клиентской частью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib) — не всё так [однозначно](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libx11/blob/master/configure.ac#L295-298):

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(xkb,
              AS_HELP_STRING([--disable-xkb],
                [Disable XKB support *EXPERIMENTAL*]),
              [XKB=$enableval],[XKB=yes])
```

т.е., в принципе, **можно** собрать *libx11* (*xlib*) без поддержки *xkb*.

а вот реально ли встретить такую сборку в «живой природе» — вопрос открытый.

на сайте [разработчиков](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/xorg/guide/extensions/#index1h2) есть слегка обнадёживающие слова:

> Programmers writing against the Xlib API will find some Xlib keyboard functions now call XKB support under the hood. Other Xlib keyboard calls are deprecated and should be replaced in applications by calls to replacement XKB functions in Xlib.

Comment: Что ж, вы меня успокоили